# What is the collective name for the power, volume, and/or function buttons on a tablet?

Tags: terminology, tech-writing

I'm trying to be the most inclusive when writing a procedure that involves usage of a tablet computing device.

I've read about hardware buttons for Microsoft Tablet PCs. I want to know if there's a more inclusive term for them on devices from other manufacturers, as well.

An example sentence would be:

> "Press the device's ____ and verify there is no response.

Comment: How about controls?

Comment: Can you add an example sentence?

Comment: Software buttons are known as "soft buttons" (as in "software"); by analogy, we might retronym all these real, physical buttons as "hard buttons" (as in "hardware") or "hard controls". Or maybe we just go simple and say "physical buttons", "physical controls".

Comment: @Azor-Ahai, an example sentence would be "Press the device's ____ and verify there is no response."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft uses "hardware buttons" and "physical buttons" [interchangeably](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gpiobtn/physical-buttons).

> ## Physical buttons
>
> Hardware buttons let users perform many common tasks that do not have a convenient user interface alternative. For the scenarios addressed in this section, the hardware buttons are typically used for tasks that occur while the physical keyboard is not available to the user, on form factors such as convertibles or slates.

You could really use either one. But as always, pick one and stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, on the iPad user guide by Apple Inc., It tells you the names of the buttons.

On an IPad Pro: 
[image: Front]
[image: Back]

On Ipad(5th generation), IPad Air, IPad Air 2:
[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't help because my intent is to group all buttons under one term.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. Miss understood the question. I’ll try to see on google :) @00Zero

Comment: @00Zero Well, There are synonyms though, but ‘button’ is the best term.